# Read flat-file from matlab

Tags: c#, matlab, file-io, binaryfiles

I want to read flat-file containing data in binary throght matlab,,,
how can i do that..?
The data actually is numbers in double saved as binary in the .dat file

thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many methods to do so, I usually use [`fread`](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/techdoc/ref/fread.html)

```
fileId = fopen('mybinaryfile.dat','r'); %# open the file for reading
myData = fread(fileId,Inf,'double');    %# read everything (Inf) in the file as 'double' values
```

If your data will hardly fit in the memory, you can access it using multiple reads

```
sizeToRead = 10000;                     %# limit size to 10000 values
fileId = fopen('mybinaryfile.dat','r'); %# open the file for reading

keepGoing=1;                            %# initialize loop
while(keepGoing)
  %# read a maximum of 'sizeToRead' values
  myData = fread(fileId,sizeToRead,'double');

  %# ...
  %# process your data here      
  %# ...

  %# make the loop stop if end of file is reached or error happened
  if numel(myData) ~= sizeToRead
    keepGoing=0;
  end
end
```

Comment: if numel(myData) ~= sizeToRead     keepGoing=0;   end 

what is this condition?

Comment: and also Mr. laurent ,,, how seek to specific position in binary file , for example i want to move the pointer(curser) from 0(begining)to 123 >>>?

Comment: if the number of read data was different from what you asked for, you are at end of file, and exit the loop.

Comment: to seek to a given position, use `fseek(fileId,numberOfBytes,'cof')`. 'double' are 8 bytes in size, so in your case you need to do `fseek(fileId,8*123,'cof')`

Comment: what is the (123)? 8 is the size of double in byte, but what 123?

also Mr. laurent how to get the current pointer position in the file:?

Answer (score 0):

Open this file using FileStream, then wrap it into BinaryReader. It gives you methods like ReadDouble, ReadByte, etc.